# FInd the area of a triangle in a circle with radius 1

Tags: geometry

In the figure above, what is the area of $\triangle \mathrm{TAB}$ using $\theta$?

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $A(\Delta TAB)=\frac{1}{2}\times AB \times \sqrt{3}\sin(\theta)$ perhaps.

Comment: I tried to use "Power of a point" which gives $PA \times PB=3$ and $AT:BT=PA:\sqrt{3}$ by similarity but It appeared to be needed 1 more relation to write PA and PB using \theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some calculation with analytic geometry, the answer is $$2\sin(\theta)\sqrt{3\sin(\theta)\sin(60^\circ-\theta)}$$